# RegEx for any amount of white space followed by a certain term and the rest of the line

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to replace all occurrences of a line that was left in our code by an old tool.

Basically I want to find this:

```
(Beginning of Line)(Any amount of white space)//CodingIssue_(anything at all until end of line)
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work, most likely due to the white space count.

```
^\s//CodingIssue_.\*
```

Comment: `\s+` (at least one space); `\s*` (zero or more spaces), `\s{5,}` (at least `5` spaces)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\s*//CodingIssue_.*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cs*%2F%2FCodingIssue_.*&i=%20%20%20%2F%2FCodingIssue_anything%20at%20all%20until%20end%20of%20line&o=m). To match *lines*, compile the pattern with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, or add a `(?m)` at the pattern start.

**Deetails**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (to stay on the same line, replace with `[\p{Zs}\t]*`)
- `//CodingIssue_` - a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than newline (if you match *lines* bear in mind that `.` also matches CR, and that is a good reason to use `[^\r\n]*` instead of `.*` here).

Comment: Thanks perfect, I added (\r\n|\r\n) to catch the end of the line for replacing them throughout the code base, doing a find all right now to peruse the results to make sure I catch nothing erroneous. Should be able to accept by the time it's finished :)

Comment: @Jay: Just FYI: the `*` I added after `\s` is a *quantifier* that matches 0 or more occurrences of the quantified pattern. And `\*` in your pattern matched a literal asterisk symbol since it was escaped.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Adding [\r\n] seems to catch any amount of new lines after the line, how do I make sure it only catches one and one only?? Thanks!

Comment: @JayCroghan: One line break pattern is `(?:\r\n?|\n)`